# How to run a simple Ruby script

Tags: ruby

I would like to make a program that checks to see if the number you enter is an even number. Sort of like making a leap year program but for any number divisible by 2.
Something along the lines of:

```
num = gets.chomp
while num != 0
  if (num%2) == 0 
    puts 'yess'
  else 
    puts 'nooo'
  end  
end
```

I knows there's something easy that I need to change for it to run.
(btw I just started learning Ruby yesterday!)

Comment: `puts 8.even? ? "yes" : "no" #=> "yes"`

Comment: Or something `num = 24
num.modulo(2).zero?  # => true`...

Comment: or, `num = 15
num.modulo(3).zero?  # => true`...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Generally, when you see behavior you don't expect, it's best to state exactly what you *are* seeing (i.e. just copy the relevant part of the output from running the program into the question itself). It's unclear from your question whether you're actually getting any output at all, or how you're trying to run it; if this is the problem, then your code (and the original title) are irrelevant.

Comment: It looks like your code, though incorrect, does not raise an exception when run.  To amplify @Kyle's comment, when you post a question about code that does raise an exception, be sure to state the exception that is raised (e.g., `ArgumentError`) and the line that raises it.  Have a look at this new-to-Stack Exchange [FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites).

Comment: Why are you treating zero as a special case? Zero is an even number.

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here.

First being something that others have put, you need to make sure you turn the input into an integer using ".to_i" on your num variable.

Secondly, this code puts you into an infinite loop since you are using a "while" loop.
Since the number is only input once, you get stuck in the "while" loop forever no matter what the input is. Basically, "num" never stops being *not* 0.

You'd be better off using an if..else statement. Something like:

```
num = gets.chomp.to_i
if num != 0
  if (num%2) == 0 
    puts 'yess'
  else 
    puts 'nooo'
  end
else
  puts "that's 0, dude"
end
```

Comment: An "if loop"? You mean an if construct? I'm upvoting anyway because you're the only person so far to point out the infinite loop, which shocks me.

Comment: Sorry, I meant an "if..else" statement. Edited.

Comment: You don't need `chomp`; `num = gets.to_i` is enough.  More generally, for example, `'1234My dog is Diva' => 1234 (Fixnum)`.  Though just a matter of style, consider writing all but the first line as ` puts (num.zero? ? "that's 0, dude" : (num.even? ? 'yess' : 'nooo'))
`. I prefer this because it's easier to read horizontally than vertically.

Comment: I agree that there are definitely much better ways of writing this code using things like ".even?", but I assumed that the user who asked this question was just starting to learn Ruby. Writing out something like the ".even?" method is a good way to learn when starting out. I appreciate the feedback though.

Comment: I would also like to point out 0 is also even, even though it's "0, dude".

Answer (score 0):

Integers have two methods for this. They are `even?` and `odd?`.

You can use this in your if statement as so:

```
if num.even? 
  puts 'yess'
else 
  puts 'nooo'
end
```

However, an easier way to write this is with ternary expressions:

```
puts num.even? ? "yes" : "no"
```

However, make sure `num` is an Integer. Anything coming from `gets` will be a String. So, you should be doing `num = gets.chomp.to_i`. Anything that is not a number, like `"h"`, will return `0`.

```
"5".to_i #=> 5
"h".to_i #=> 0
```